# MSSQL query where to include city name Abbreviations

Tags: sql, sql-server

Have search on my site and user need to input a city name.

Even though I have an auto complete from my database in city input they can still type any name.

So the db table will have city names such as:

- Saint Paul
- St. Louis

And user can input "Saint Louis" / "St Louis"

and i still need there to be a result from table even though it is not an exact match.

The same goes for Mt/Mt./Mount and so on.

How can this be achieved?

Thanks

Comment: You can use Full-Text indexed Search

Comment: Maybe a table with all common aliases for cities, and rather search this one?

Comment: Dont allow users to enter anything - give them a drop down list of options

Comment: Don't let them search the Cities table. Let them search the CitiesAliases table where you have added St. Paul -> Saint Paul and Saint Paul -> Saint Paul.

Comment: @abhay-prince "Full-Text indexed Search"  I create a catalog and index and am now querying the table but do not understand how I can get ti to work.
  select City
  from customtable_Area
where contains(City, 'St') 

Only returns City with "St" and "St."  but not "Saint".

How am I suppose to query to cover all options?